# instagram REDIRECT URI ios scheme not accepted

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

no matter what it do i can't register my redirect uri

> scheme://...
>   "ig"+"CLIENT_ID"+"://"

I refresh my browser, uses, chrome,safari,i.e. 
Nothing works
It only works if i actually start the redirect uri with "http:"

Comment: Man I have the same problem, I swear 3 days ago it worked. All my others start with custom protocols and can't change it anymore. Now I'm trying to battle redirecting it from example.com to myapp://whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instagram doesn't let you use scheme:// anymore. I solve this problem by redirect it to my website and set up a php script to redirect the code information back to my app.

Answer (score 1):

I just used http://aoir4w57wrdsahfosafdhla.local. This is accepted by Instagram; I then added a proper intent filter like this to my activity:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="aoir4w57wrdsahfosafdhla.local"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

The upside is that I don't need my own page set up, just to handle Instagram. The downside is that after Instagram login, Android asks whether to open the link with Chrome or my app. Well, Instagram, allow me to use any scheme and I'll fix this.